# Conservation of energy

Tags: automotive

I recently was on a walk to a supermarket and I saw a car that was been charged, they connected the jumper leads from one car to another. but on the way back I saw the car was running idle. Eventually, I tried googling to see whether or not a car can charge its battery by running its alternator or idle, but I was like: how can it charge if the conservation of energy law states that you can't make energy, how can you charge a car battery by running it on idle if the engine requires a battery(for things like spark plugs).

Comment: Cars recharge their batteries by using the engine to generate electrical power.  When the car is "idle" in this case it is actually turning gasoline into electrical energy which is stored in the battery.  Thus energy is conserved.

Comment: yeah and infact 90% of the energy stored in the gas is wasted as heat in the process.

Comment: @Gabrielashmore the car engine does not use the battery when it is running ... your whole question seems to be based on somewhat flawed understanding of automobile engines

Comment: @jstola a car engine uses battery for both timing(in better cars), and spark plugs

Comment: @Gabrielashmore While the engine is running electrical power is supplied by the alternator rather than the battery.  The battery is only used to start the car, and in some engines can even be disconnected while the engine is running (although usually not a good idea).

Answer (score 2):

> how can it charge if the conservation of energy law states that you can't make energy, how can you charge a car battery by running it on idle if the engine requires a battery(for things like spark plugs)

Because the engine is burning gasoline, and the energy it gets from the gasoline is hundreds or thousands of times more than the energy it uses to fire the spark plugs and run the other electrical loads, so it can run a generator from the motor to recharge the battery, with plenty left over to move the car (if it wasn't idling). In the end, the gasoline provides the energy needed to fire the spark plugs, light the headlights, and even start the car — the battery is only a temporary *storage*, needed because otherwise everything would stop when the motor stopped.

Some old cars, some small motors (like in lawnmowers or chainsaws), and even some semi-recent airplanes, don't have any battery at all; you turn on the ignition, and then you start the motor turning manually (with a crank for the old cars, with a pull-cord for the lawnmower, or by turning the propeller by hand (very carefully!) for the airplanes). Once the motor is running, it can generate the electricity needed to *stay* running, but it's used immediately — no storage.

Comment: Some newer fully electronic outboard motors also have no battery. The first pull on the starter cord charges up capacitors that run the ECU and EFI, ignition, etc. Second pull actually starts the motor. So I have read. I have not seen one up close yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun question you can elaborate until the ducks come home.
Lets give this a try:

**The system boundaries:**

Lets assume a so called isolated system (no mass or energy flow across the system boundaries) here. Our system, therefore consists of the two cars, their batteries and fuel. Imagine it as a big cube in space only with the two cars inside if you want. This is system A.

**What does this imply?**

Under the assumption that energy is conserved and the requirements for an isolated system (A) are not violated your question is a very 'tickling' one. From observing, as you did, that the batteries are charged by an idling motor there must be some sort of energy flux from somewhere to the batteries **within** the system (A).

**So far only fancy talk:**

No lets up our game once again here. We now define a so called 'closed system' around the volume of the battery we are interested in. To be a valid closed system, there must be no mass flow across the boundaries - but energy flow can be. From the fact, that the battery is charge, we can derive, that there is a non zero energy flow through the leads connected to the battery. This is system B. You can imagine it as a cube within the A cube only containing the battery. You could call it a sub-system.

**Back to the roots:**

But where is this energy coming from? From the engine one could reason. So lets define a so called 'open system' around the engine. This allows for energy and mass flow across its boundaries. This is our system C. Fuel is pumped to the engine (mass flow) to be oxidized (exothermic) to produce heat. The oxygen is introduced as mass flow from system A to system C. The exhaust gases are also a mass and heat flow from system C to system A. Heat is another word for energy. Most of the heat from the combustion is radiated to the surroundings. Some of it is converted into motion by the pistons and the crankshaft within the engine. Some of this motion energy is then converted to electric energy. This energy is used to charge the battery and power the electronics required in a modern engine - but also stuff like spark plugs. These conversions are all energy flows. And there is your circle closed.
Energy from the battery is changed to motion (starting the engine) which then produces energy at a higher rate by oxidizing fuel (idling) to charge the battery again.

**Does this answer have to be so long?:**

The heck: NO! But you can also fill books to answer it on the other hand. But my point is not to waste your time reading this - but rather to animate you to think about 'thermodynamics' as a strongly philosophic topic. May I respond with some questions to you?

1. If you include the gas station to your mental construct: What systems can there be defined?
2. If you add the earth into your considerations: What systems can there be defined? And where does the energy come from?
3. If you include the entire universe? Where does the energy come from?

You see: A 'simple' question like 'How is a battery charged in a car?' can be expanded into questions like 'What is entropy?' and 'Where does the root energy come from?' - and these are deep questions to some of us.

**Have fun with thermodynamics - can recommend.**

Answer (score 1):

The internal combustion engine (ICE) converts chemical energy (fuel) into mechanical energy. Some of that mechanical energy is used by the alternator to generate electricity, which keeps the battery fully charged in spite of the fact that the engine control unit (ECU) and ignition system, etc are consuming electrical energy.

Each step is less than 100 percent efficient. The chemical potential energy of the fuel being burned is much higher than the mechanical output of the ICE. The mechanical input to the alternator is higher than the electrical output of the alternator.

So there is no violation of conversation of energy when the fuel consumption is included in the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

A car with a dead battery can borrow another car's battery and charging system by jumping it (hence jumper cables). The right way to do that is to connect the cables and let the good-battery car run for a bit: its alternator will top off both the dead battery and its own. Then, the dead-battery car can be started.

So there's three flows of energy in this process:

- Connect the cables and wait: from 'good' battery car alternator to 'dead' battery via jumper cables
- Turn the key: from 'now-not-dead' battery and from 'good' (via jumper cables) to the starter
- Running, disconnect the cables: from 'now-not-dead' car alternator to its own battery, charging it

Once started, the dead-battery car's alternator will take over continue to charge its own battery as well as run the accessories. That's the main idea: it's the alternator that provides the main electrical energy when running, even at idle, not the battery. The battery is mainly for start-up and standby power.

Ultimately, all these flows originate as burning dead-dinosaur juice in each engine. Energy is conserved even if a good portion of it is wasted as heat due to inefficiency.